# How to change the default directory where programs get installed

Tags: debian, software-installation, directory-structure

I have Debian wheezy chrooted in my Android. However all its directory is in my internal memory. So, if I `apt-get install` something, it gets installed in  `/data/data/.../debian/usr/local/bin` directory.

I have bound my external sd under `/sdcard/sdext2` in Debian.

I can access it by cd `/sdcard/sdext2` and verified with `ls` that it is ok.

I would like to have Debian install apps under `/sdcard/sdext2/usr/local/bin` instead of `/usr/local/bin`. How can I do that without moving the whole root directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian does not install anything into `/usr/local`, in the sense that official Debian packages are forbidden to touch that hierarchy. Also, Debian packages can assume absolute installation paths, so they may not work correctly if moved by hand (or by somehow tricking `dpkg` into installing them into a different hierarchy).

On the other hand, software packages using the GNU Autotools build system (ie. those you install by `./configure && make && sudo make install`) indeed use the `/usr/local` hierarchy by default, and you can override that:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/sdcard/sdext2/usr/local
```

You may want to override other default directories, too.  Browse the output of `./configure --help` for those not influenced by `--prefix`.